# How to display Android database data in a ListView?

Tags: android, database, listview, layout

I'm making an app that shows in its main layout Database datas, that contains two kind of strings: titles and authors.

I managed to use the second layout to register these datas, but can't manage to show them.

This's my databaseHelper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Statement SQL (database creation)
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table book (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, author text not null);";

// Constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// This method is called during database creation
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

// This method is called during database upgrade, for example while incremented version number
@Override
public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) {

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book");
        onCreate(database);

}
}
```

This is my DbAdapter:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DbAdapter {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String LOG_TAG = DbAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

// Database fields
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "book";

public static final String KEY_BOOKID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";

public DbAdapter(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
}

public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
  dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
  database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
}

public void close() {
  dbHelper.close();
}

private ContentValues createContentValues(String title, String author ) {
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put( KEY_TITLE, title );
  values.put( KEY_AUTHOR, author ); 
  return values;
}

//create a book
public long createBook(String title, String author ) {
  ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(title, author);
  return database.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//update a book
public boolean updateBook( long bookID, String title, String author ) {
  ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(title, author);
  return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, KEY_BOOKID + "=" + bookID, null) > 0;
}

//delete a book      
public boolean deleteBook(long bookID) {
  return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_BOOKID + "=" + bookID, null) > 0;
}

//fetch all books
public Cursor fetchAllBooks() {
  return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_BOOKID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR }, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//fetch books filter by a string
public Cursor fetchBooksByFilter(String filter) {
  Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                                  KEY_BOOKID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR },
                                  KEY_TITLE + " like '%"+ filter + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);

  return mCursor;
}
}
```

Then, my main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    Button newbook_btn;
ListView BookList;
private Cursor cursor;
private DbAdapter dbHelper;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    newbook_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.newbook_btn);
    newbook_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                    public void onClick(View aView)
                    {
                           Intent toAnotherActivity = new Intent(aView.getContext(), NewbookActivity.class);
                           startActivityForResult(toAnotherActivity, 0);
                    }
            }
    );
    ListView BookList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Finally, my last activity (to register new datas into database):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.***.DatabaseHelper;
import com.***.DbAdapter;

public class NewbookActivity extends MainActivity {

private DbAdapter dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_newbook);
    dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
    Button addnewbook_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    addnewbook_btn.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View aView) {
                dbHelper.open();
                EditText editTextTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String TitleValue = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
                EditText editTextAuthor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String AuthorValue = editTextAuthor.getText().toString();
                if (TitleValue.matches("") && AuthorValue.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(NewbookActivity.this, "You didn't entered the book info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }else if (TitleValue.matches("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewbookActivity.this, "You didn't entered the book Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }else if (AuthorValue.matches("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewbookActivity.this, "You didn't entered the book Author", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }else{
                    dbHelper.createBook(TitleValue, AuthorValue);
                    dbHelper.close();
                    Toast.makeText(NewbookActivity.this, "The book has correctly added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent toAnotherActivity = new Intent(aView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(toAnotherActivity, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

}
```

Please, any help?

Comment: Cant see you putting data in your ListView. The only code related to it is - ListView BookList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); your initialization?

Comment: Where are you trying to show the data? I can't see any code about that.

Comment: @AtulOHolic : dunno where to find relative lines needed to do it. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @BobanS. : read what I told AtulOHolic :)

Comment: check http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html and http://androidituts.com/android-database-listview-example/ and http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/learn-how-to-create-listview-from-sqlite-database-in-android-development/

Comment: @AtulOHolic : already seen. But cannot manage to print my registered data too. It's my first app, and really don't understand what are the rules to make them showing. Also, all these links that I saw, and that you linked to me, are showing how to show and also create database, with different rules. Can you help me understanding - with my database rules - how to display inserted datas? Please :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Lets take this step by step. See this - http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html and work on the displayListView() where will pass the data you get from the fetchAllBooks() to your adapter via Cursor. See how they have mapped each data to respective view which will form the item of your ListView. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need a method to create a `List<String>` from the `Cursor` you get by the `DBAdapter`.

```
public List<String> cursorToList(Cursor c) {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            data.add(/*String created from c*/);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Then you need to create an adapter to help populate your `ListView`. This adapter will store your `List<String>` and the format to display it.

```
/* In the onCreate method of MainActivity*/
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(/*context*/this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    cursorToList(/*get your cursor here*/dbHelper.fetchAllBooks()));
```

Finally you need to set this adapter to the `ListView` and you are done.

```
BookList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is a basic `ListView` which will show a `String` for every object. For a more customized `ListView`, you can extend the `ArrayAdapter` class.